# fastest way to search first repetitive value in an unsorted integer array of 10 numbers?

Tags: php, search

What can be the fastest way to search first repetitive value in an unsorted integer array of 10 numbers?

What should be the answer if the array has 10 million records?

Comment: Is the array sorted, or unsorted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way i can think of is using 2 array since you want `first repetitive value in an unsorted integer`

10 million ??? Not sure of memory implication

[PHP DOC Comment](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php)

> Memory footprint of splFixedArray is about 37% of a regular "array" of the same size.
>   I was hoping for more, but that's also significant, and that's where you should expect to see difference, not in "performance

[How big are PHP arrays (and values) really? (Hint: BIG!)](http://nikic.github.com/2011/12/12/How-big-are-PHP-arrays-really-Hint-BIG.html)

Example

```
$array =  SplFixedArray::fromArray(array(1,2,4,6,4,2,7,7,3,3,1));
$list = array();
foreach ($array as $value ) {
    if (in_array($value, $list)) {
        echo $value;
        break;
    }
    $list[] = $value;
}
```

Output

```
 4
```

Comment: using `foreach($array as $value)` is 10 times faster than using ArrayIterator (I did a benchmark for 1000000 records). For 10000000 records php reached memory limit in both cases :D

Comment: [SplFixedArray](http://am1.php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php) should be used, when size of array is known. According to comments at php.net, 'memory footprint of splFixedArray is about 37% of a regular "array" of the same size'!

Comment: An interesting article is [here](http://nikic.github.com/2011/12/12/How-big-are-PHP-arrays-really-Hint-BIG.html)

Comment: @bhovhannes nice i'll update my answer ... but i can see it only faster for large array ....

Comment: of course @Baba, for small arrays difference should be negligible, but it was mentioned a huge size - 10 million items, so I thought that SplFixedArray can be used.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the smallest repeated number then

- Sort the array with Radix sort in O(n) time
- Loop through the sorted array and find the first repeat

If you want the first repeated number in whatever order the array is already in then

- Loop through the array adding the numbers to a Hash Set until you reach a number that you can't add to the Hash Set because it's it already exists.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://nikic.github.com/2011/12/12/How-big-are-PHP-arrays-really-Hint-BIG.html). PHP arrays internally are using Hash Set structure, so they are designed to be fast.

Answer (score 1):

Here is benchmark code. It was too big to fit into comment, so I put it as separate answer.

```php
<?php
$array = range(0, 10000);


$time_start = microtime(true);
$list = array();
foreach ( $array as $value ) {
    if (in_array($value, $list)) {
        echo $value;
        break;
    }
    $list[] = $value;
}
printf("Using foreach loop:<br/>%0.10f<br/><br/>", microtime(true)-$time_start);


$time_start = microtime(true);
$list = array();
foreach ( new ArrayIterator($array) as $value ) {
    if (in_array($value, $list)) {
        echo $value;
        break;
    }
    $list[] = $value;
}
printf("Using ArrayIterator:<br/>%0.10f<br/><br/>", microtime(true)-$time_start);
```

`foreach` loop is faster than `ArrayIterator`.

I tried with 10000 elements. Elements were generating with [range](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) function, which ensured I have 'the worst' input array, where all elements are different.

With 1 million records array generation took too long on my machine.